# How to upload/download file on azure files storage?

Tags: c#, azure

How to upload and download file on azure files storage.
Also I need to get list of the files and display into data grid view.

Comment: This is not only too broad and unclear, it shows absolutely no attempt. This is not how this site works. Please read [ask]

Comment: What you mean by no attempt?

Comment: @VigneshRaja - Meaning, your original question is essentially just a requirement, along with "how do I do this?" This shows no attempt, no effort, just... "write code for me." And this isn't how the site works. Hence the comment about not showing effort.

Answer (score -2):

```
        CloudStorageAccount cloudStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(YOUR_CONNECTION_STRING);

        CloudFileClient fileClient = cloudStorageAccount.CreateCloudFileClient();

        // Locate the directory. ( Sharename\Root\Dir1\Dir2 )
        CloudFileDirectory cfDir = fileClient.GetShareReference("app-updates").GetRootDirectoryReference().GetDirectoryReference("test").GetDirectoryReference("v1");

        // Get File Reference
        CloudFile cloudFile = cfDir.GetFileReference("testFileOnCloud.txt");

        // Upload
        cloudFile.UploadFromFileAsync(@"D:\toupload.txt", FileMode.Open);

        // Download 
        cloudFile.DownloadToFileAsync(@"D:\downloaded.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate);

        // Get file List
        List<CloudFile> lstFiles = cfDir.ListFilesAndDirectories().OfType<CloudFile>().ToList();

        dataGridView1.DataSource = lstFiles.Select(x => new { Name = x.Name, Size = x.Properties.Length}).ToList();
```

Comment: Code dumps are not considered answers on this site. Please read [answer]

Comment: Any developer who knows to code in C#, can understand the above answer.

Comment: @TomSun - You shouldn't be updating someone's answer with words they never said. This is an invalid edit. Also: by you posting what you did, it makes Camilo's comments seem really odd (in that it was just a code dump). As such: I've rolled back your edit.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto - apologies - someone had modified the answer with text that wasn't from the answerer. I rolled this edit back, which now clearly shows it was, indeed, just a code dump.

Comment: I get a compile error : 'IListFileItem' does not conain a defenition for 'DownloadToFile' and no extention method 'DownloadToFile' accepting a first argument of type 'IListFileItem' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) when I try the download to file line , any ideas to why is that ?